# FileExistsError: [WinError 183] No se puede crear un archivo que ya existe

Tags: python, python-3.x

una vez que el directorio esta creado , al ejecutar el codigo da el siguiente error:
¿como puedo hacer para que si ya existe ese directorio, la función continuae escribiendo el archivo

---

FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1

----> 2 fetch_genome("X51500.1", "genseqs")

in fetch_genome(genome_id, directory)
      9     url_template = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=%s&rettype=fasta&retmode=text"

10

---> 11     os.mkdir(directory)

12

13     genome_id = genome_id.strip()

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] No se puede crear un archivo que ya existe: 'genseqs'

```
import requests
import os
import sys
import time

def fetch_genome(genome_id, directory):

       url_template = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=%s&rettype=fasta&retmode=text"

       os.mkdir(directory)

       genome_id = genome_id.strip()

       print("Fetching ", genome_id, "...")

       out_file = os.path.join(directory, genome_id + ".fa")
       if os.path.exists(out_file):
            print("already fetched")

       resp = requests.get(url_template % genome_id)
       open(out_file, "w").write(resp.text)
       print("Done")
       return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente `os.mkdir` lanza una excepción si el directorio ya existe:

> If the directory already exists, FileExistsError is raised.

Tienes varias podibilidades, entre ellas:

- Usando `os.mkdir` pero capturando la excepción (válida también para Python 2.x):

  ```
  try: 
      os.makedirs(directory)

  except OSError:
      if not os.path.isdir(directory):
          raise
  ```
- Usando [`os.mkdirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) con el parámetro `exist_ok=True`:

  ```
  os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
  ```
- Usar la biblioteca [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (Python >= 3.5):

  ```
  import pathlib
  pathlib.Path(directory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  ```

  Aunque el método existía ya en Python 3.4 el parámetro `exist_ok` no se introdujo hasta la versión 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Corregí este error eliminando el directorio, antes del comando makedirs, así:

```
rmdir(name)
makedir(name, exist_ok=exist_oK)
```